# JDK version 1.5 beta

Tags: oracle, java

I need to find the next JDK:

java version "1.5.0-beta"

Java(TM) 2 Runtime Environment, Standard Edition (build 1.5.0-beta-b32c)

Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 1.5.0-beta-b32c, mixed mode)

I tried to find on the Oracle site, but I unfortunatelly I found nothing. Are there any other places where this version of JDK can be downloaded?

Comment: Why would anyone want an old beta release?

Comment: My friend got such question on interview, the idea is to test his abilities with internet finding =)

Comment: That was an interview question? Run far away from that company.

Answer (score 2):

The latest JDK is a Java 7 release - specifically Java 7.0u7.

The Java 1.5 (aka Java 5) release was "end of lifed" nearly 3 years ago.  The latest / last publicly released version of Java 5 released was Java 5.0u22, and you can get it from the [Java SE 5.0 Downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase5-419410.html) page.  Later releases of Java 5.0 are only available to people with Oracle Java support contracts.

As far as I'm aware, old "beta" releases for Java 5.0 are not available anywhere.

Comment: Yes, but old versions are also present on oracle site, so, I think it is possible to find 1.5 as well.

Comment: First of all I completely agree with Stephen. A simple google search tells thatIBM has released a Beta version of 1.5.0 way back. More info: http://www.theserverside.com/news/thread.tss?thread_id=37049

Comment: @Chris - that's referring to a release for AIX and you need an IBM client ID to even check if the release is still downloadable.

Comment: @Stephen C actually I found few links from sites like rapidshare links (also torrents). I wanted to give the content only from genuine sites